# Unity2D object rotation on Mobile device

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I want to know if there is a way to rotate the object only when the user click and drag on the gameobject. If the user click and drag anywhere else, the gameobject should not rotate.
Object with this script on it is rotating no matter where the user clicks.

```
void Update()
{
   

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        

        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
      
       

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector2 dir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position) - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(transform.position);
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle - 90, Vector3.forward);
            transform.rotation = rotation;


           transform.rotation = rotationZ * transform.rotation;


        }
     


    }
```

Comment: Could you please include the code you are currently using?

Comment: I simply dont understand how nobody cant help and tehre is not answer anywhere on internet,is it imposible to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Your current code indeed only checks for touches .. it doesn't matter whether these are "hitting" anything or not.

You could e.g. use a [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) in order to check if your touch is above an object using

```c#
// store the direction from object to touch when the touch started
private Vector2 startDirection;
// store the objects orientation when the touch started
private Quaternion startRotation;
// only process touch moved if the touch actually started above this object
private bool isValidTouch;

// The collider of this object
[SerializeField] Collider _collider;
// The main camera
[SerializeField] Camera _mainCamera;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!_collider) _collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    if(!_mainCamera) _mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
      
        var touchPosition = touch.position;

        switch(touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                // Check if this touch actually is over this object
                if(_collider.RayCast(_mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touchPosition), out var hit))
                {
                    // Now store initial data
                    // You want to do ONLY ONE:
                    // - Either transform the touch into worldspace (more complicated)
                    // - OR transform the position into screenspace (easier)
                    // You definitely do not want to do both!
                    startDirection = (touchPosition - (Vector2)_mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position));
                    startRotation = transform.rotation;
                    isValidTouch = true;
                }
                break;
        
            case TouchPhase.Moved
                if(isValidTouch)
                {
                    // Get the current touch direction
                    var direction = (touchPosition - (Vector2)_mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position));
                    // Get the angle between them
                    var differenceAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(startDirection, direction, Vector3.forward);
                    // rotate the original rotation according to the current angle
                    Quaternion rotation = startRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(differenceAngle, Vector3.forward);
                    transform.rotation = rotation;
                }
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Ended
               isValidTouch = false; 
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but now i have problems bcs i am using it in 2d game,and it is not possible subtract Vector3 and Vector2

Comment: @HardWork sorry may bad .. 1. it should have been `WorldToScreenPoint` in order to transform the position into screen space coordinates of course ^^ 2. Youc an simply cast it (`(Vector2)....`) .. updated it in the answer

Comment: Thanks man no problem,but i have misunderstood for Raycast sry,Raycast cant be converted t oVEctor2,and thank you so much